# JAVA cannot receive UDP through sockets without a valid route item to the sender, but tcpdump can capture them

Tags: java, linux, sockets, routes, tcpdump

I write a JAVA program on RHEL6.8 to receive UDP packets with socket. Without a valid route table on both sender and receiver, the socket cannot receive the UDP but I can run tcpdump to capture the UDP. 
After route table modification, the JAVA code can successfully get the UDP.

Is it a LINUX restriction or JAVA socket issue?

thanks,

Comment: channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));
while (isRun) {
 if (queue != null){
  data = UDPBufferPool.allocate();
  sourceAddr = (InetSocketAddress) channel.receive(data
    .getByteBuffer());
  dp = data.getDatagramPacket();
  dp.setAddress(sourceAddr.getAddress());
  dp.setPort(sourceAddr.getPort());
  dp.setLength(data.getByteBuffer().position());
  } 
}